# chaining promises in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

Im learning promises so i made simple site that generates content via ajax.

when user clicks on link it changes the content of the site but first it should fade out the original content.

I have made script that call promises and return content

```
function getcontent(url){
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xhttp.onload=function(){
        if(xhttp.status==200){
            resolve(xhttp.response)
        }
        else{
            reject(Error(xhttp.responseText))
        }
      }
      xhttp.send();
    })
    }
```

and function that should add content

```
function change(url){
    var doc=document.getElementsByClassName("info")[0];
    return getcontent(url).then(function(x){

        doc.children[0].classList.add("remove");
        return x
    }).then(function(x){
        doc.removeChild(doc.children[doc.children.length-1]);
        var div=document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML=x;
        doc.appendChild(div)
    })
}
```

to be more clear , the element which will have class added has

```
-webkit-transition:15s ease all;
```

so i want to, make it , that original content should fade out , and after that the ajax content should be added to the site. Thats why i used promises. I thought promises chaining waits for .then() method to complete and thene execute next .then() method. But the ajax content is added to the site before original content fades so its called before first .then() method is finished. Did i  miss something?

I tried to do it in two separated functions using ontransitionend event as comment suggets but it just wont work

```
function getcontent(url){
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.onload=function(){
    if(xhttp.status==200){
        resolve(xhttp.response)
    }
    else{
        reject(Error(xhttp.responseText))
    }
  }
  xhttp.send();
})
}

function change(url){
    var doc=document.getElementsByClassName("info")[0];
     getcontent(url).then(function(x){
     return new Promise(function(res,rej){
    doc.addEventListener("transitionend",function(){
      res(x);
    })});
    doc.children[0].classList.add("remove")

    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each then callback is called in order, and the promise will wait when a  new promise is returned in the previous callback. The problem with your code is that promises do not wait for css animations. And since it does not wait it goes to the next callback and removes your element right away.

You can create(and return) a new promise in the first `then`, and for that promise use a [transitionend event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) to resolve/reject that new promise. This will make the promise wait till the transition is done and then execute the next callback

```js
var prom = new Promise(function(res,rej){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://cors-test.appspot.com/test", true);
  xhttp.onload=function(){
    console.log("loaded");
    if(xhttp.status==200){
      res(xhttp.response)
    }
    else{
      rej(Error(xhttp.responseText))
    }
  }
  xhttp.send();
});

prom.then(function(data){
  var old = document.querySelector("#content");    
  
  return new Promise(function(res,rej){
    old.addEventListener("transitionend",function(){
      res(data);
    });
    old.classList.add("remove");
  });
}).then(function(data){
  var parent = document.querySelector("#parent");
  var old = document.querySelector("#content");
  old.remove();
  var div=document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML="Data retrieved, length: "+data.length;
  parent.appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
.remove {
  opacity:0;
}

#parent div {
  -o-transition:all 2s;
  -moz-transition:all 2s;
  -webkit-transition:all 2s;
  transition:all 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"><div id="content">Content</div></div>
```

Comment: im trying to make it in two separates functions and it does not works i updated my question with code i tired now

Comment: @trolkura, because you are removing the class in the wrong part, put the `.add('remove')` call in right after the addEventListener call like in my code example